# Why are columns and values data lost in pd.concat?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, jupyter

**User Experience** 
I am recent engineering (Not C.S.) graduate with basic proficiency in MATLAB. I have no prior experience with Python/Jupyter. I have scoured SO and google for help but cannot find a similar issue. The code for this project is based on the following article:
https://medium.com/@shahrezanjum/using-python-to-automate-fantasy-football-stats-in-madden-ff9020fc2d2d

**Motivation**
Madden is a NFL video game. In franchise mode, players can cooperatively play as different teams in the same league. Madden has the ability to output player statistics for this league as CSV files. CSV files are separate, and are organized in folders by week and by team. As such, this output format requires modification in order to perform data analysis.
[See Madden output structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTZV9.png)

**Problem Statement**
The objective is to concatenate these CSVs into a single CSV file to facilitate data analysis.
Madden CSV column orders are not identical.
The code I have so far has two issues:
1)The values for the first column "defCatchAllowed" is missing ONLY for the first data frame.
2)The values for the column "fullName" is missing values for every data frame after the first.

**Code Strategy**
Unlike the code in the link, I see 3 objectives for the code:

1. Find all CSV files for a given week.
2. Fill in blank cells with a value of zero.
3. Concatenate CSV files. (Concat can sort columns so different col orders for df's is ok.)

Here is the code that I have so far:

-Create DFs from CSV (starting with just 3 df, will add all teams when code works)

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/Justin/Desktop/MADSTADT/stats/reg/PullHere/49ers/player-stats.csv", \
              index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0], engine = 'python')
df2 = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/Justin/Desktop/MADSTADT/stats/reg/PullHere/Bears/player-stats.csv", \
              index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0], engine = 'python')
df3 = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/Justin/Desktop/MADSTADT/stats/reg/PullHere/Bengals/player-stats.csv", \
              index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0], engine = 'python')
```

-Reset index (I didn't think this was necessary since concat can sort columns but commenting it out caused more issues)

```
list_dataframes = [df1, df2, df3]
for dataframe in list_dataframes:
dataframe.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
```

-Fill NaN values with 0.

```
list_dataframes3 = [df1, df2, df3]
for dataframe in list_dataframes3:
dataframe.fillna(value = 0, inplace = True)
```

-Concatenate dfs

```
finaldf = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], sort = True)
```

**Output**
[CSV output file. Highlighted cells indicate problem areas.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBWMJ.png)

**Misc Thoughts**
At first I thought there was an issue with defCatchAllowed being the first column so I created a for loop to add an extra column in front to be filled with zeroes to avoid the problem but that did not work.

I tried reindexing columns as the linked article described but this produces no different output than what the above code already does.[Reindexing that does not appear to do anything.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3KE6.png)

Based on SO searches and google I cannot find the answer to this problem. Interested in hearing more experienced users thoughts on where I should look for the troubleshoot.

I am new to SO so let me know if I am missing any information. Your feedback is appreciated.

**Update per Recommendations**
I attempted option number 3 - adopt a common column order.

I used this code to reorder the columns [image: Column reorder for each df]

I get this error code telling me "defCatchAllowed" is not in the index.[image: Error code] That's ok with me so I remove "defCatchAllowed" from the column reorder and then it throws the same error code but for "fullName". I'm not sure where I should go next.

**Solution**
Per accepted solution, I updated the code to for loop append each data frame with no sorting. Once complete I reset the index for the resulting df. We also discovered that when reading the CSV into a data frame, the index_col=0 was creating the problem where data would be lost on the first column (defCatchAllowed or fullName). Upon removing this from the read CSV steps the code now works as intended:

```
from os import chdir
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

df1 = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/Justin/Desktop/MADSTADT/stats/reg/PullHere/49ers/player-stats.csv", \
              parse_dates=[0], engine = 'python')

list_dataframes = [df1, df2, df3]
for dataframe in list_dataframes:
dataframe.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)

list_dataframes3 = [df1, df2, df3]
for dataframe in list_dataframes3:
dataframe.fillna(value = 0, inplace = True)

final_df = pd.DataFrame()
list_dataframes10 = [df1, df2, df3]
for dataframe in list_dataframes10:
final_df = final_df.append(dataframe, sort=False)
final_df = final_df.reset_index(drop=True)

output_df = final_df.fillna(value = 0)

output_df.to_csv(r"/Users/Justin/Desktop/MADSTADT/OUTPUTHERE/Reciever")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you append, I believe it should pair up the columns correctly, and if one has a column while the other doesn't, it'll add that column (but obviously will be nulls in the dataframes that don't have it:

Also, don't specify the index, just simply read in the csvs:

try:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/Justin/Desktop/MADSTADT/stats/reg/PullHere/49ers/player-stats.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/Justin/Desktop/MADSTADT/stats/reg/PullHere/Bears/player-stats.csv")
df3 = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/Justin/Desktop/MADSTADT/stats/reg/PullHere/Bengals/player-stats.csv")


final_df = pd.DataFrame()
list_dataframes = [df1, df2, df3]
for dataframe in list_dataframes:
    final_df = final_df.append(dataframe, sort=False)

final_df = final_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - I implemented this section of code after the fill.na cell. I commented out the concat cell and implemented this. When I display(final_df) it is blank and the output CSV is blank as well.

Comment: Updated solution per debugging input.

Answer (score 0):

The core issue is having a disjoint set of columns across [df1,df2, df3]... and these need to be wrangled to a normalized set of columns?  If this is not the problem, stop here.

Recommend one should define the `norm set of columns` for downstream analysis.   Choices are:

1. drop unneccessary columns per df
2. rename N diff columns into 1 normalized column name & format
3. normalize all to common format
4. categorize all `similiar` columns to unified identifiers... e.g. name + fullname -> playerID

Beyond this, one has to see specifics.   Wrangling is messy.

Comment: Hi - thank you for your response. 1) How should I go about normalizing all columns to a common format?I tried that with the commented code in section "Reindexing that does not appear to do anything". 2)Would this issue relate to the first column on df1 still having NaN (fillna - unsuccessful)

Comment: Hi - I will attempt to normalize all columns to a common format and report back.